# My code has created a numpy array inside another numpy array for one list but it does not for another list that goes through the exact same process

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, artificial-intelligence

I'm developing a simple Artificial Intelligence for a college project and so far it has worked until it randomly began creating a numpy array inside another numpy array. One of the lists that are being converted is a dataset that I've created myself that then is iterated through and each image is read by cv2 and added to a new list. This new list is then converted into a numpy array (this is the one that causes the problem). A second, smaller list (test images) goes through the same process and comes out with the desired result.

This is the code for the dataset, each string is a file name.

```
images = ['Dana C zero 1.png','Dana C zero 2.png','Dana C zero 3.png','Dana C zero 4.png','Dana C zero 5.png',
          'Dana C zero 6.png','Dana C zero 7.png','Dana C zero 8.png','Dana C zero 9.png',
          'Dana C zero 10.png','Dana C zero 11.png','Dana C zero 12.png','Dana C zero 13.png','Dana C zero 14.png',
          'Dana C zero 15.png','Dana C zero 16.png','Dana C zero 17.png','Dana C zero 18.png','Dana C zero 19.png',
          'Dana C one 1.png','Dana C one 2.png','Dana C one 3.png','Dana C one 4.png','Dana C one 5.png',
          'Dana C one 6.png','Dana C one 7.png','Dana C one 8.png','Dana C one 9.png',
          'Dana C one 10.png','Dana C one 11.png','Dana C one 12.png','Dana C one 13.png',
          'Dana C one 14.png','Dana C one 15.png','Dana C one 16.png','Dana C one 17.png',
          'Dana C one 18.png','Dana C one 19.png','Dana C two 1.png','Dana C two 2.png','Dana C two 3.png',
          'Dana C two 4.png','Dana C two 5.png','Dana C two 6.png','Dana C two 7.png','Dana C two 8.png',
          'Dana C two 9.png','Dana C two 10.png','Dana C two 11.png','Dana C two 12.png','Dana C two 13.png',
          'Dana C two 14.png','Dana C two 15.png','Dana C two 16.png','Dana C two 17.png','Dana C two 19.png',
          'Dana C two 20.png','Dana C three 1.png','Dana C three 2.png','Dana C three 3.png',
          'Dana C three 4.png','Dana C three 5.png','Dana C three 6.png','Dana C three 7.png','Dana C three 8.png',
          'Dana C three 9.png','Dana C three 10.png','Dana C three 11.png','Dana C three 12.png',
          'Dana C three 13.png','Dana C three 14.png','Dana C three 15.png','Dana C three 16.png',
          'Dana C three 17.png','Dana C three 18.png','Dana C three 19.png',
          'Dana C four 1.png','Dana C four 2.png','Dana C four 3.png','Dana C four 4.png','Dana C four 5.png','Dana C four 6.png','Dana C four 7.png',
          'Dana C four 8.png','Dana C four 9.png','Dana C four 10.png','Dana C four 11.png','Dana C four 12.png','Dana C four 13.png','Dana C four 14.png',
          'Dana C four 15.png','Dana C four 16.png','Dana C four 17.png','Dana C four 18.png','Dana C four 19.png',
          'Dana C five 1.png','Dana C five 2.png','Dana C five 3.png','Dana C five 4.png','Dana C five 5.png','Dana C five 6.png','Dana C five 7.png',
          'Dana C five 8.png','Dana C five 9.png','Dana C five 10.png','Dana C five 11.png','Dana C five 12.png','Dana C five 13.png','Dana C five 14.png','Dana C five 15.png',
          'Dana C five 16.png','Dana C five 17.png','Dana C five 18.png','Dana C five 19.png',
          'Dana C six 1.png','Dana C six 2.png','Dana C six 3.png','Dana C six 4.png','Dana C six 5.png','Dana C six 6.png','Dana C six 7.png',
          'Dana C six 8.png','Dana C six 9.png','Dana C six 10.png','Dana C six 11.png','Dana C six 12.png','Dana C six 13.png',
          'Dana C six 14.png','Dana C six 15.png','Dana C six 16.png','Dana C six 17.png','Dana C six 18.png','Dana C six 19.png',
          'Dana C seven 1.png','Dana C seven 2.png','Dana C seven 3.png','Dana C seven 4.png','Dana C seven 5.png','Dana C seven 6.png',
          'Dana C seven 7.png','Dana C seven 8.png','Dana C seven 9.png','Dana C seven 10.png','Dana C seven 11.png','Dana C seven 12.png',
          'Dana C seven 13.png','Dana C seven 14.png','Dana C seven 15.png','Dana C seven 16.png','Dana C seven 17.png','Dana C seven 18.png','Dana C seven 19.png',
          'Dana C eight 1.png','Dana C eight 2.png','Dana C eight 3.png','Dana C eight 4.png','Dana C eight 5.png','Dana C eight 6.png',
          'Dana C eight 7.png','Dana C eight 8.png','Dana C eight 9.png','Dan C eight 10.png','Dana C eight 11.png','Dana C eight 12.png',
          'Dana C eight 13.png','Dana C eight 14.png','Dana C eight 15.png','Dana C eight 16.png','Dana C eight 17.png','Dana C eight 18.png','Dana C eight 19.png']
readyImages = []
readyLabels = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                        1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
                        2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,
                        3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,
                        4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,
                        5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,
                        6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,
                        7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,
                        8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8])
testImages = ['Dana C zero 20.png','Dana C one 20.png','Dana C two 18.png','Dana C three 20.png','Dana C four 20.png','Dana C five 20.png',
              'Dana C six 20.png','Dana C seven 20.png','Dana C eight 20.png']
readyTestImages = []
testLabels = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The code below is the two for loops used to create the list of "prepared images"

```
for i in range (0, len(images)):
  img = cv2.imread(images[i])
  readyImages.append(img)
for i in range (0, len(testImages)):
  img = cv2.imread(testImages[i])
  readyTestImages.append(img)
```

These two 'ready' lists are then turned into numpy arrays with the following code:

```
readyImages = np.array(readyImages)
readyTestImages = np.array(readyTestImages)
```

After this, the 'readyImages' array looks like this:

```
array([array([[[179, 179, 179],
        [185, 185, 185],
        [204, 204, 204],
        ...,
        [181, 181, 181],
        [182, 182, 182],
        [179, 179, 179]],

       [[218, 218, 218],
        [229, 229, 229],
        [237, 237, 237],
        ...,
        [228, 228, 228],
        [229, 229, 229],
        [229, 229, 229]],

       [[240, 240, 240],
        [252, 252, 252],
        [253, 253, 253],
        ...,
        [252, 252, 252],
        [252, 252, 252],
        [254, 254, 254]],

       ...,
```

(The rest of the array I have not included as it is massive)
The 'readyTestImages' array looks like this (normal):

```
array([[[[255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255]],

        ...,
```

All of the images, testing and training, are 28x28 so that is not the cause of the problem (as it has already caused issues before which have been solved)
I do not know what is causing this issue but it is preventing my program from running.
Incase its helpful, while the given data is trying to run through the neural model(code below):

```
train_images = readyImages
train_labels = readyLabels
test_images = testImages
train_images = train_images / 255.0


model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28, 3)),
                          keras.layers.Dense(784, activation = 'relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(128, activation = 'relu'),
                          keras.layers.Dense(10, activation = 'softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-93cf1c129e74> in <module>()
      2 train_labels = readyLabels
      3 test_images = testImages
----> 4 train_images = train_images / 255.0
      5 
      6 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it and I can send or add any information needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
for i in range (0, len(images)):
  img = cv2.imread(images[i])
  readyImages.append(img)
```

`cv2.imread` can fail (e.g., if the image file is truncated), in which case `img` will be `None`. When you convert a list with `None` to numpy array, some elements in the array will be also `None`, so when you try to normalize the images dividing by 255 you get the reported error.

Add a check on `img` to ensure the image loaded correctly, then discard the matching labels for the images that fail loading.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll implement that next time I access the code. Should I do the same for the other for loop?

Comment: In principle yes, but from the printout of the array it seems you don't have None values in there (you can tell because the first one has multiple "array(" while the last one has just one before all the data

Comment: use `img is not None`, not `!=`

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a go